# peewee regexp works only the first time

Tags: python, regex, peewee

I'm running into an issue with the peewee regexp function. Queries like this work the first time I run it:

```
query = Table.select().where(Table.column.regexp('string'))
```

However, if I try to run it with a different string, I get this error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'regexp':

```
query = Table.select().where(Table.column.regexp('string2'))
```

I usually run it twice because I need to see how specific to make the regexp string.

I've tried disconnecting/reconnecting to the db, but that doesn't help. The only thing that works is if I close ipython and restart it. Is this a memory/buffer issue? Is there a good way to get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/415

Comment: At some point in your code are you assigning a value to `Table.column`?  Possibly `Table.column = <something>`?

Comment: Update: moved to github & closed there w/no resolution. Using MySQL to query & peewee to pull data directly into python. https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/417#issuecomment-52256402

Comment: Another update: if I do a few things in between and then try another regexp query, it works... I'm wondering if the db is locked somehow from the prior query & it just takes time to release it?